# SAP VBS fails to playback recording

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I'm automating some reports using visual basic. I've recorded some scripts that worked fine by seem to have stopped working for reasons unknown. I record the following (comments added) and the script fails at a file dialog box.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 95,22,false
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "se16"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
' Run AGR_TCODES
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDATABROWSE-TABLENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'Select Extended Name, Multiple selection
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_I3_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 23
' select file
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "c:\my_directory\"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "myfile"
session.findById("wnd[2]").sendVKey 0
```

Its at this point in script playback that the script just stops with the file select text inputs blank. I can type the information in, but that kinda defeats the purpose. I can't find the reasons or a cause, but lots of various upgrades have occurred, including my laptop and a reinstall of the os to WIN10.  I don't really care why - but I do need to find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios I've identified:

1. It appears that SAP occasionally loses the focus of dialog boxed. Use gratuitous .setfocus commands on the window to compensate
2. It appears that uploads via scripts may be blocked by security settings. You can do it manually, but not via script. A telltale sign is that when you record the script, your inputs are not recorded. So the DY_FILENAME.text line will be completely missing from the recording. I'm not sure how to fix this, but at least you know where to look!

Good luck with your scripts.